# 401 Unauthorized error while trying to pull image from Google Container Registry

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, google-container-registry

I am using google container registry (GCR) to push and pull docker images. I have created a deployment in kubernetes with 3 replicas. The deployment will use a docker image pulled from the GCR.

Out of 3 replicas, 2 are pulling the images and running fine.But the third replica is showing the below error and the pod's status remains "ImagePullBackOff" or "ErrImagePull"

> "Failed to pull image "gcr.io/xxx:yyy": rpc error: code = Unknown desc
> = failed to pull and unpack image "gcr.io/xxx:yyy": failed to resolve reference "gcr.io/xxx:yyy": unexpected status code: 401 Unauthorized"

I am confused like why only one of the replicas is showing the error and the other 2 are running without any issue. Can anyone please clarify this?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3):

**ImagePullBackOff** and **ErrImagePull** indicate that the image used by a container cannot be loaded from the image registry.

[401 unauthorized error](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting#401_unauthorized_cannot_pull_images_from_private_container_registry_repository) might occur when you pull an image from a private Container Registry repository. For troubleshooting the error:

1. Identify the node that runs the pod by `kubectl describe pod POD_NAME | grep "Node:"`
2. Verify the node has the storage scope by running the command

   ```
   gcloud compute instances describe NODE_NAME  --zone=COMPUTE_ZONE --format="flattened(serviceAccounts[].scopes)"
   ```
3. The node's access scope should contain at least one of the following:

   serviceAccounts[0].scopes[0]: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only
   serviceAccounts[0].scopes[0]: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
4. Recreate the node pool that node belongs to with sufficient scope and you cannot modify existing nodes, you must recreate the node with the correct scope.

   - Create a new node pool with the gke-default scope by the following command

     ```
     gcloud container node-pools create NODE_POOL_NAME  --cluster=CLUSTER_NAME  --zone=COMPUTE_ZONE   --scopes="gke-default"
     ```
   - Create a new node pool with only storage scope

     ```
     gcloud container node-pools create NODE_POOL_NAME   --cluster=CLUSTER_NAME  --zone=COMPUTE_ZONE --scopes="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only"
     ```

Refer to the [link](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting#ImagePullBackOff) for more information on the troubleshooting process.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you will setup role for cluster to access GCR images for pulling and pushing you can see https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/issues/336

Comment: Thanks for your reply @vndark. My doubt is, like I mentioned above, 2 replicas of the deployment are pulling the image from GCR and working fine. Only the 3rd replica is providing the error.